# Replace HTML5 video with GIF if it cannot auto-play

Tags: html, html5-video

I'm embedding an HTML5 video as a background that auto-plays, which works as of iOS 10, but on earlier versions, it only shows an image with a play button (not shown on iOS 10). In these cases, I'd like to display a GIF as a fallback to always provide an option that automatically plays without a play button or user interaction, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this. Should I simply check the iOS version in JavaScript and replace the element or is there a similar method to the `onerror` `source` attribute?

Here's my video:

```
<video id="home-bg-video" poster="img/bg.png" autoplay loop muted playsinline>
  <source src="vid/bg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll have to check using JavaScript as you indicated. I don't think there is a way to do it in HTML alone.

Comment: @RacilHilan Thanks for the confirmation. I found a script to detect the exact iOS version, so I'll take it from there.

Comment: Could you hide the video off-screen, and only move it on screen in the onplay event handler? Wouldn't that be better than detecting iOS version?